# Vue.js: How can I set a background image during "mounted" of a component?

Tags: css, vue.js, background-image

The imageName shall be changed by a variable. In the end I want the component to have a background image depending on an parameter in it's URL.

```
<template>
  <div :style="background-image: {{imageName}}">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name:"niceName",
  data:()=> ({
    imageName:"",
  }),
  mounted() {
    imageName="@/assets/images/backgrounds/img/"+anyVariable.anyImgName;
  }
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to `require()` the image, so that the `@`-alias can be resolved.

```html
export default {
  mounted () {
    this.imageName = require(`@/assets/images/backgrounds/img/${dynamicPath}`)
  }
}
```

Also: in your `<script>`, you have to use `this.[property-name]`, since without it, you'd set a local variable which only exists in `mounted()`-scope.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to lyashi I could find this solution:

```
<template>
  <div :style="{backgroundImage:'url('+imageName+')'}">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name:"niceName",
  data:()=> ({
    imageName:"",
  }),
  mounted() {
    this.imageName=require('@/assets/images/backgrounds/'+anyVariable.anyImgName);
  }
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Thy magic is in the :style= syntax with the curly braces.